# Select statement to retrieve xml output as below

Tags: sql-server-2005, xml

Could someone provide me some clues or solution to retrieve record sets like below?

Note: I read the msdn documentation but leads me no where but hair loss :(

Just for the assumption think i have 2 tables connected via Rid field

Table 1 columns:

```
 Rid, UserName, Hash
```

Table 2 columns:

```
 Rid, Phone, City, Email
```

`Table1` and `Table2` are connected via the `Rid` column.

I would like to have a xml output using xml auto, or xml explicit or which ever xml operations you got in SQL Server 2005 Express.

Output expected:

```
<UserDetails>
    <Account>
        <UserName>
        </UserName>
        <Hash>
        </Hash>
    </Account>
    <Personal>
        <Phone>
        </Phone>
        <City>
        </City>
    </Personal>
</UserDetails>
```

@matt Please look into the procedure I created below. When you execute the stored procedure with code at start you will know the problem I face

```
stack_getusers  '<Request Type="GetUsers" CRUD="R">
                            <UserDetails>
                                <Rid></Rid>
                            </UserDetails>
                        </Request>'

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stack_getusers]    
@doc NTEXT    
AS    
DECLARE @idoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc    
SELECT 
    t1.UserName AS "Account/UserName",
    t1.Hash AS "Account/Hash",
    (
        SELECT t2.Phone AS "Personal/Phone",
               t2.City AS "Personal/City"
        FROM table1 t2
            INNER JOIN table2 t3 ON t2.rid = t3.rid WHERE t2.rid = t1.rid AND (xml.Rid = '' OR t1.rid = xml.Rid)
        FOR XML PATH('Personals')
    )
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.rid = t2.rid
OPENXML (@idoc,'/Request/Users',2)
WITH (Rid int) as xml
where (xml.Rid = '' OR t1.rid = xml.Rid)
FOR XML PATH ('UserDetails');
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    t1.UserName AS "Account/UserName",
    t1.Hash AS "Account/Hash",
    t2.Phone AS "Personal/Phone",
    t2.City AS "Personal/City"
FROM table1 t1

    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.rid = t2.rid

FOR XML PATH ('UserDetails');
```

I have added a second code sample in response to your comment.  I have no idea if this will work, or if it is even the best way to accomplish what you want it to.  Please let me know.

```
SELECT 
    t1.UserName AS "Account/UserName",
    t1.Hash AS "Account/Hash",
    (
        SELECT
            t2.Phone AS "Personal/Phone",
            t2.City AS "Personal/City"
        FROM table1 t2

            INNER JOIN table2 t3
                ON t2.rid = t3.rid

        WHERE t2.rid = t1.rid

        FOR XML PATH('Personals')
    )
FROM table1 t1

    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.rid = t2.rid

FOR XML PATH ('UserDetails');
```